# SQL get values within quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

im encountering the following issue i have a couple of strings in SQL and try to get just a little part off of it and i cant get it to work.

Examples of my strings:

```
{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Id":0,"Value":"Stackoverflow"}

[{"@odata.type":"#Mmake.this.short","Id":1,"Value":"Stackoverflow1"},{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Id":2,"Value":"Stackoverflow2"}]

{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|name@email.nl","DisplayName":"Lastname F. (Firstname)","Email":"Name@email.nl","Picture":"https://picture.com/","Department":null,"JobTitle":null}
```

Now im trying to write a stored procedure and get the following values back:

Stackoverflow

Stackoverflow1,Stackoverflow2

and name@email.nl

I tried working with SUBSTRING, LEN, RIGHT, CHARINDEX and REVERSE but i cant seem to get what i need. The value of Value: can ofcourse be of different lenghts for each record.

My idea was to count the total string (len string)
then get the first " on the right and subtract that from the total string.
then i would try and get the second " and subtract that from the first. whats left is the value inside and i could use a substring.

But that would only work for the first one, the others are quite different and somehow i cant even get the first to do what i like. (i cant seem to get the 2nd " on the right)

i hope this is enough info so you could point me in the right direction to fix this problem.

Thankyou

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, because the functions you reference are SQL Server functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are on SQL Server 2017 you should be using the JSON functions for this

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Id":0,"Value":"Stackoverflow"}','$.Value')

SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Claims":"i:0#.f|membership|name@email.nl","DisplayName":"Lastname F. (Firstname)","Email":"Name@email.nl","Picture":"https://picture.com/","Department":null,"JobTitle":null}','$.Email')


SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Value') ,',')
FROM OPENJSON('[{"@odata.type":"#Mmake.this.short","Id":1,"Value":"Stackoverflow1"},{"@odata.type":"#make.this.short","Id":2,"Value":"Stackoverflow2"}]','$')
```

Comment: Im working with SQL Server 17, and this works like a charm indeed. I can just use the 2 values i get form the last one to make one string from it again.

I am just wondering if you could tell me a bit more about why this works because i cant get my head around it tbh.

Comment: Your strings are in `JSON` format. `JSON_VALUE` is a function to extract scalar values from JSON, `OPENJSON` gets a tabular result set (for each element in the array in this case). See [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for more about them

Comment: And as you are on 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` to get your desired result for the last one